# How to write log statements that are agnostic to logging implementation

Tags: java, logging

I'm writing a java library and I want to include logging statements, but I have no way of knowing what logging framework (log4j/slf4j/jul) the code calling my library is using.

In Java, I know you can use generic annotations like @Inject work with multiple libraries (Spring/Guice). Is there a way I can do something conceptually similar with my logging?

Basically, I want to be able to write `log.info(...)` and have that work as expected regardless of what logging framework is being used.

Comment: Did you look at [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/)?

Comment: The obvious solution is to create yet another log wrapper of your own :) `/s` I'm not offering a suggestion here. It's a mess, and the blame lands on Sun/Oracle.

Comment: Good call Abhijith, SLF4J seems to be exactly what I needed!